# what does it mean to temper chocolate?

Tags: chocolate, tempering

When working with chocolate you often melt it down and let it harden in a new shape or on top of or around another ingredient.

What does it mean to "temper" chocolate

Comment: See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11643/what-is-the-purpose-of-tempering-chocolate

Comment: If the duplicate does not answer your question, could you please explain what you are looking for?

Comment: Going ahead and closing; if you have something else in mind feel free to clarify and we can reopen!